# Custom Authentication In MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a custom auth set up so that a user is stored as a session variable. Once they go through the Account/LogIn process I store the details returned from a 3rd party API as a user in the session like this:

```
Session["User"] = new UserViewModel(result);
```

I want to check the user is present before every controller action so I have made a BaseController with the following check in it:

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
  if (Session["User"] != null)
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
  else
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "LogIn", controller = "Account" }));
```

Each of the controllers then inherits from the BaseController so that it redirects to the Log In page if there is no user. I don't inherit from the BaseController for the AccountController so that it doesn't get in an infinite loop of checking and redirecting, but I also want to have specific pages not check for log in. Is there any way to do this, i.e. write an exception rule in the same way that you might have [AllowAnonymous]?

Comment: Why not create a custom Authorize attribute, and apply it only to controllers you want this check to be performed?

Comment: Override the Authorize Attribute instead of ActionFilters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a filter on those methods as:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ActionCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        string controllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName.ToLower().Trim();
        string actionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName.ToLower().Trim();

        // this is just a sample.. you can implement any logic you want
        if (!actionName.StartsWith("your method name") && !controllerName.StartsWith("your controller name"))
        {
            var session1 = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            //Redirects user to login screen if session has timed out
            if (session1 == null)
            {
                base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

                filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
                {
                    controller = "Account",
                    action = "LogOff"
                }));
            }
       }

    }
}
```

then on the controllers put the attribute as:

```
[ActionCheck]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

or on specific action methods as:

```
[ActionCheck]
public Actionresult SomeMethod()
{
    return View();
}
```